# Swift MVVM, segue's and uialertcontrollers

Tags: swift, mvvm

Im trying to convert a swift app from mvc to mvvm. I've put most my logic into a view model layer behind view controller but struggling how to cleanly calls segue's, alertcontrollers.

These obviously need to be called from view controller but the logic to call them is made in the ViewModel. I cant think of an elegant solution to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: MVVM does not make suggestions how to solve navigation. You may take a look at the [Viper architecture](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8440907-getting-started-with-the-viper-architecture-pattern). Here, the "Router" implements the navigation tasks, which is connected to the "Presenter" (the ViewModel in MVVM). You may think of "Segues" an implementation detail of a lower level, and you may add an API to your MVVM architecture that performs navigation without mentioning segues.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a protocol with these functions to be able to call its function in your viewModel